# How to setup a program to change quantities in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I have a somewhat specific question.  I have a list of items that will be chosen in the program and then need to separate the quantities of the number into different amounts.

Here is an example:
10 pipes get separated into a set of 3 which are 2 + 5 + 3.  These 2, 5, and 3 are sent to different locations, which is why we need to separate them.

I am using C# and trying to think of the best tool to use in a Form based application.  What would be the best way to get the quantities when some materials can be separated into over 100 different locations?

Edit: will ask the second part of this question in another question on ui.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might want to consider posting this on http://ui.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: How would a user know, for example, that location A should have 3 pipes sent to it.  Could the ratio for the splitting be derived through code, or is manual input definitely required?

Comment: Is your question "what UI should I present to the user, so that they can decide how to split up the quantities?"

Comment: Manual input is required for the different locations, it is known at the time the materials arrive.  And this does deal with the UI, I did not know of ui.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a slider, why not use a numerical spinner?

Comment: A spinner would work very well, since the numbers can range by a large amount, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :) you should also check out the .minvalue and .maxvalue properties of the spinner, it'll help keep validation in the UI component (if needed). Also check out NumericUpDown.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a minimum and maximum quantity why don't you use a slider? Then the user can choose how many locations to separate the materials into.
Using a dinamic slider would prevent user input errors or at least drastically decrease them.